# Time lag between signals using numpy.correlate()

Tags: python, numpy, cross-correlation

I want to calculate the time lag between some signals using cross correlation function in Python. From the numpy documentation [numpy.correlate()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html), It is not very clear that what exactly this function does. Therefore,I try it first with two simple square signals with the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

frequency=100

x = np.linspace(1,2000,frequency)
time = np.arange(x.size)
time = time/(1.0*frequency) #Time in seconds

def func1(x):
    x = np.where((x < 500) | (x > 531), 1, 2)
    return x
y1 = func1(x)

def func2(x):
    x = np.where((x < 600) | (x > 631), 1, 2)
    return x
y2 = func2(x)

def func3(x):
    x = np.where((x < 700) | (x > 731), 1, 2)
    return x
y3 = func3(x)

xcorr12 = np.correlate(y1,y2, "full")
xcorr13 = np.correlate(y1,y3, "full")

lag12 = np.argmax(xcorr12)
lag13 = np.argmax(xcorr13)

print ("lag12:",lag12/frequency)
print ("lag13:",lag13/frequency)
```

When I change the position of the signals, I expect the time lag to change, but it does not! I do not understand why i get the time lag between y1 and y2 is equal to lag between 1 and y3 !?

Can you help me understand what is happening? 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that the y1 and y2 arrays are calculated in a manner that you wanted

```
np.count_nonzero(y1)
20
np.count_nonzero(y2)
15
```

Then

```
xcorr = np.correlate(y1,y2, "full")
np.count_nonzero(xcorr)
34
```

With almost sparse matrix(array) lag will not change,you know this from signal processing and maths.
Take a look at this small example

```
y1 = [1,2,3,4]
y2 = [1.0,0.5,1.0,2.0]
```

And we get

```
xcorr = np.correlate(y1,y2, "full")
array([  2. ,   5. ,   8.5,  13. ,   7.5,   5. ,   4. ])
```

If we move values in second array

```
y21= [0.0,1.0,0.5,1.0]
```

Then resulting xcorr looks

```
array([ 1. ,  2.5,  5. ,  7.5,  5. ,  4. ,  0. ])
```

The problem you have is the sparsity of your matrix.It does not have to do anything with this Python package.You can double-check results with R,you will get the same values.

Comment: Okay, I changed the example signal. now there is no zero value. still, the problem is not solved. why i get the time lag between y1 and y2 is equal to lag between y1 and y3? :(

Comment: I have asked there already, but the post is put on hold as off-topic there!
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/293969/time-lag-between-signals-using-numpy-correlate

Comment: @user8224662 Often seems the way there - now that link is a dead one...

Answer (score 0):

Your correlation in both cases has the same distribution. Try to replace x = `np.where((x < 500) | (x > 531), 1, 2)` with `x = np.where((x < 500) | (x > 531), 0, 2)`.

Then you can compute lag
`lag12 = np.argmax(xcorr12) - (Nx -1)` where Nx is len(y1) and len(y2)

```
def getLag(x,y):
    Nx = len(x)
    if Nx != len(y):
        raise ValueError('x and y must be equal length')
    correlation = np.correlate(x, y, mode=2)
    return np.argmax(correlation)- (Nx -1)
```